# How can I insert values to an object property of an array?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The thing is that I don't know if there is something wrong with how I insert the data with the post or if the problem is with the HTML syntaxis of how I try to access the properties of an object property of an array.

This is my model and I would like to insert for example a value in "cantidad" of "MaterialesProductos" array.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const ProductoSchema = new Schema({

IdProducto:{type:String},
MaterialesProductos:[{nombre:{type:String},cantidad:{type:Number}}],
precio:{type:Number},
image:{type:String},
nombre:{type:String},
descripcion:{type:String},

});

const Producto = mongoose.model('Producto',ProductoSchema);
module.exports = Producto;
```

This is my post where I insert all data with a "req.body".  Always get the array empty.

```
const Producto = require('../models/Productos.js')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
    

    let image = req.files.image;
    image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname,'..','public/img',image.name),async (error)=>{
    await Producto.create({
    ...req.body,
    image: '/img/' + image.name

    
    })


    res.redirect('/AgregarProductos')
    })
    }
```

I've already tried with MaterialesProductos[].cantidad or MaterialesProductos[][cantidad] etc but I just can't insert the value.

```
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
               <input type="button" name="abrirse" id="open" value="Agregar materiales">
                     <div id="popup" style="display: none;">

                        <div class="content-pop">
                            <div><a href="#" id="close">X</a></div>

                            <% for (var a = 0; a < materiales.length; a++) { %>
<div>
<%=materiales[a].Descripcion%>
<input type="number" value="0" name="MaterialesProductos.cantidad" min="0">
</div>
                                <% } %>
                    </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I researched and didn't find a solution. So I had to do it manually.

With `MaterialesProductos[nombre]` (can be anything) I get the values in an array with `req.body.MaterialesProductos[nombre]` I access to it..
Using `$push` (I can't insert or create it so I just can `updateOne`) I first create the document and after I update it adding the array with both objects.

Something like this:

```js
const Producto = require('../models/Productos.js')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
  let image = req.files.image;
  image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public/img', image.name), async (error) => {
    await Producto.create({...req.body,
    image: '/img/' + image.name
  })
  for (a=0; a<req.body['MaterialesProductos[cantidad]'].length;a++) {
    if (req.body['MaterialesProductos[cantidad]'][a]!=='0') {
      await Producto.updateOne({
        nombre: req.body.nombre
      },{
        $push: {
          MaterialesProductos: {
            nombre: req.body['MaterialesProductos[nombre]'][a],
            cantidad: req.body['MaterialesProductos[cantidad]'][a]
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
  res.redirect('/AgregarProductos')
 })
}
```

And worked.

[image]